# QTextBrowser html link not clickable

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextbrowser

I am trying to add a link to a QTextBrowser and allow it to be clicked.  I can get the link to display properly, but when I hover over it the mouse does not change at all (as if it were a URL to click) and you can't click it.

I have setReadOnly and setOpenExternalLinks to True for the QTextBrowser and properly formatted the html url.

```
self.playlist_txt = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
self.playlist_txt.setReadOnly(False)
self.playlist_txt.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

url_link = "https://google.com/"
html = '<a href="'+url_link+'">'+url_link+'</a>'
print html
self.playlist_txt.setHtml(html)
```

Output of "html":

```
<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure which Qt you're using (guessing Qt4 from `QtGui.QTextBrowser()`) but Qt5 documentation of `QTextBrowser` says this: This class extends QTextEdit (in read-only mode), adding some navigation functionality so that users can follow links in hypertext documents.

Comment: Using Qt4.  I'm not sure what you are trying to say though?  I made a link, I can't click it to open the link.  Thats expected behavior.

Comment: @Zak44 remove `self.playlist_txt.setReadOnly(False)`

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc!  That worked.  I can give credit if you want to post the answer.

Comment: @Zak44 It is done

Comment: @Zak44 It tells you exactly the same thing as the answer - you can navigate links from QTextBrowser only if it's in read-only mode. In other mode, it works as a QTextEdit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make the QTextBrowser be readonly so that the url can be clicked and open the url:

```py
self.playlist_txt.setReadOnly(False)
```